# counting number of distinct pairs such that i<j and A[i] =/= A[j]

Tags: algorithm, distinct

I'm trying to solve this in `O(n log n)` time. Given a sorted array `A`, how can I determine the number of distinct pairs with the requirements `i < j` and `A[i]` and `A[j]` be different numbers?

An example would be `A = [1, 2, 3, 3]`, distinct pairs would be `(1,2), (1,3), (2,3)` returning `3`.

Comment: Your example indicates you're asking for the number of distinct pairs *of values* (i.e., distinct pairs `(A[i], A[j])`), but your question could also be interpreted as asking for the number of distinct pairs *of indices* (i.e., distinct pairs `(i, j)`).

Answer (score 4):

Scan array left to right to find unique elements count

```
if (A[i] != A[i-1])
    uniq_count++
```

Note that time is linear `O(n)`

For the number of unique elements `M` number of pairs is

```
M*(M-1)/2
```

Why? The first element forms `M-1` pairs with tne next elements. The second one forms `M-2` pairs (one has been already counted) and so on. Result is sum of aritmetic progression.